# Unbounded fork function is Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to understand the following homework.

Let $s>0$ and $u: \Bbb{R}\rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be:
$$
u(x)=
\begin{cases} 
1/x^s, & 0< x\leq 1 \\ 0,& \text{otherwise.} 
\end{cases}
$$
I need to show that

1. $u\in \mathcal{M}_\mathbb{R}^+(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ for all $s>0$
2. and determine for which $s>0$ that $u\in \mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$

For (1) My idea is that it is a continuous function in the interval and therefore it is Borel measurable and furthermore always positive.

For (2) I think that $u \in \mathcal{L}^1(\lambda)$ when $s\geq 2$ because it is then a convergent series. But my problem is that $u\rightarrow\infty$ when $x\rightarrow 0$. I know there exists unbounded function that are Lebesgue integrable but I don't know how to determine or show it for this function.

Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: You introduce the positive number $s$, but you do not use it inside your question: what is its meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea about the measurability is correct.

Now i pressume that you mean with $s>0$ that $u(x)=\frac{1}{x^s}$ when $x \in (0,1]$

For $0<s<1$ the function is integrable and you can also compute its integral.

For $s \geq 1$ we have that $$\int_0^1 u(x)dx \geq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{\frac{1}{2n+2}}^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}\frac{1}{x^s}dx$$ $$ \geq  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (2n+1)^s\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}$$ $$= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^{s-1}}{2n+2}$$ $$\geq  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)^{s-1}}{4n}=+\infty$$ since $s-1 \geq 0$

Comment: Why is it integrable for $0<s<1$? And what about the case $s=1$?

Comment: I edited my answer..i also included s=1..its the same..the series diverges if $s-1 \geq 0$...for s<1 and the positivity of u you can compute the integral..a non-negative measurable function is lebesgue integrable if $\int f <+\infty$..so just compute the integral.

Comment: Another version of the problem is the same but for $x\geq 1$. Here I would say that $u\in \mathcal{L}^1$ only if $s\geq2$ because it is then a convergent series. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes  for $x \geq 1$ you have integrability.

Comment: But only for $s\geq 2$?

Comment: Its is also true for $s>1$ and $x \geq 1$ of course.